# Why TNS Error in Oracle Database Trace Files

Tags: oracle, solaris, tns

I have a database running in oracle 11G.
It has below errors in its trace file. 
Does it impact any performance or causing any slowness ?

```
Fatal NI connect error 12537, connecting to:
 (LOCAL=NO)

  VERSION INFORMATION:
    TNS for Solaris: Version 11.2.0.4.0
    Oracle Bequeath NT Protocol Adapter for Solaris: Version 11.2.0.4.0
    TCP/IP NT Protocol Adapter for Solaris: Version 11.2.0.4.0
  Time: 04-SEP-2019 07:00:01
  Tracing not turned on.
  Tns error struct:
    ns main err code: 12537

TNS-12537: TNS:connection closed
    ns secondary err code: 12560
    nt main err code: 0
    nt secondary err code: 0
    nt OS err code: 0
opiodr aborting process unknown ospid (13538) as a result of ORA-609
Wed Sep 04 07:03:24 2019
ORA-01555 caused by SQL statement below (SQL ID: f467srusn1111, Query Duration=0 sec, SCN: 0x0c93.05004d3a):
SELECT OBJECT_ID, SUBPROGRAM_ID, OWNER, OBJECT_NAME, PROCEDURE_NAME, OVERLOAD, OBJECT_TYPE FROM DBA_PROCEDURES WHERE (OBJECT_ID, SUBPROGRAM_ID) IN ((:1 ,:2 ),(:3 ,:4 ),(:5 ,:6 ),(:7 ,:8 ),(:9 ,:10 ),(:11 ,:12 ),(:13 ,:14 ),(:15 ,:16 ),(:17 ,:18 ),(:19 ,:20 ))
Wed Sep 04 07:59:00 2019
ORA-01555 caused by SQL statement below (SQL ID: f467srusn1111, Query Duration=0 sec, SCN: 0x0c93.05004d3a):
SELECT OBJECT_ID, SUBPROGRAM_ID, OWNER, OBJECT_NAME, PROCEDURE_NAME, OVERLOAD, OBJECT_TYPE FROM DBA_PROCEDURES WHERE (OBJECT_ID, SUBPROGRAM_ID) IN ((:1 ,:2 ),(:3 ,:4 ),(:5 ,:6 ),(:7 ,:8 ),(:9 ,:10 ),(:11 ,:12 ),(:13 ,:14 ),(:15 ,:16 ),(:17 ,:18 ),(:19 ,:20 ))
Wed Sep 04 08:00:01 2019
}
```

Comment: https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/1121357_1.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the error ora-1555. An ora-1555 is raised when you do not have enough space in your rollback segments. You need to check the configuration of your rollback segments/undo.